# Spark streaming with version > 2.1.1 is slower than 2.1.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application with Spark 2.1.1 and after the upgrade in higher version I have worse performance (higher computation time, based on UI statistics). Specifically, I compare it out of the box with  the following spark versions 2.3.1, 2.3.3, 2.4.3 and 2.4.4 (latest).

I compare the configuration Spark configuration pages and I didn't find something suspicious. About my case, I use Pyspark, the application is a streaming api which reads from Kafka, do some aggregations and writes in parquet files in HDFS.

Does anyone knows what it has changed in the configuration and the performance has become worse?

Comment: Could be several things, if you are using DStream instead of Structure Streaming in the later versions also using pyspark is always slower and can have variation in performence, or just the way your Kafka is partitionned comapred to your number of executors impacting performence from time to time.